Branch and bound algorith for transportation
I'm trying to apply B&B algorith for transportation problem, but in the result I receive "No feasible solution found" and I cannot understand why it happens. Correct answer is 210.
In the output I need to receive optimal solution, number of nodes and iterations and allocation of transportation flows.
Thanks in advance for any your help.
import numpy as np
import heapq

# Node class to represent each branch in the tree
class Node:
    def __init__(self, level, cost, assignment, supply_left, demand_left):
        self.level = level  # depth of node (number of assignments made)
        self.cost = cost  # current cost
        self.assignment = assignment  # current assignment
        self.supply_left = supply_left  # remaining supply for each supply point
        self.demand_left = demand_left  # remaining demand for each demand point
    
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.cost < other.cost  # for priority queue comparison

# Cost calculation function (objective function)
def calculate_cost(cost_matrix, assignment):
    total_cost = 0
    for supply_idx, demand_assignments in enumerate(assignment):
        for demand_idx, assigned_amount in enumerate(demand_assignments):
            if assigned_amount > 0:
                total_cost += cost_matrix[supply_idx, demand_idx] * assigned_amount
    return total_cost

# Branch and Bound Algorithm for transportation problem
def branch_and_bound(cost_matrix, supplies, demands):
    num_supplies, num_demands = cost_matrix.shape
    pq = []  # priority queue for branch and bound nodes
    root = Node(0, 0, [[0] * num_demands for _ in range(num_supplies)], supplies[:], demands[:])  # initial node
    heapq.heappush(pq, root)
    
    best_cost = float('inf')  # store the minimum cost
    best_assignment = None
    node_count = 0  # count number of nodes explored
    total_iterations = 0  # to track iterations (steps in the process)

    while pq:
        node = heapq.heappop(pq)  # get the node with the lowest cost
        node_count += 1
        total_iterations += 1  # count this as an iteration
        
        if node.level == num_supplies:  # All supply points have been processed
            # Check if all demands are met (i.e., no demand left unfulfilled)
            if node.cost < best_cost and all(d == 0 for d in node.demand_left):
                best_cost = node.cost
                best_assignment = node.assignment[:]
        else:
            # Explore all demands for the current supply
            for demand_idx in range(num_demands):
                if node.supply_left[node.level] > 0 and node.demand_left[demand_idx] > 0:
                    # Determine the amount to assign
                    assign_amount = min(node.supply_left[node.level], node.demand_left[demand_idx])
                    
                    # Create new assignment
                    new_assignment = [row[:] for row in node.assignment]
                    new_assignment[node.level][demand_idx] = assign_amount
                    
                    new_supply_left = node.supply_left[:]
                    new_supply_left[node.level] -= assign_amount
                    
                    new_demand_left = node.demand_left[:]
                    new_demand_left[demand_idx] -= assign_amount
                    
                    new_cost = calculate_cost(cost_matrix, new_assignment)
                    
                    # Only add the child node if it does not exceed the best cost found
                    if new_cost < best_cost:
                        child_node = Node(node.level + 1, new_cost, new_assignment, new_supply_left, new_demand_left)
                        heapq.heappush(pq, child_node)

    return best_assignment, best_cost, node_count, total_iterations

Example usage with the specified data:
supplies = [17, 8, 10, 9]   # supply capacities
demands = [6, 15, 7, 8, 8]  # demand requirements
cost_matrix = np.array([
    [10, 8, 5, 9, 16],    
    [4, 3, 4, 11, 12],    
    [5, 10, 29, 7, 6],    
    [9, 2, 4, 1, 3]
])

best_assignment, best_cost, nodes_explored, iterations = branch_and_bound(cost_matrix, supplies, demands)

if best_assignment is not None:
    print("Best Cost:", best_cost)
    print("Best Assignment:")
    for row in best_assignment:
        print(row)
else:
    print("No feasible solution found.")
    
print("Nodes Explored:", nodes_explored)
print("Iterations Made:", iterations) 


No feasible solution found after how many iterations and nodes explored? Please post the complete results you are getting. It could be that you have to explore deeper to find the solution.

@Cincinnatus  Results are:
No feasible solution found!
Number of nodes explored: 246
Total number of iterations: 246

246 is a very low number, so a solution should have been found. Are you completely sure the input data you provided has a solution? You say that the correct answer is 210, how do you know that? Have you don't the calculation by hand? If so, then you know at each step what the results should be. Run the algorithm in debug mode line by line until you find a discrepancy. If the data is too large, create a smaller example that also fails to find a solution and then do the debugging in this smaller example. Either there's indeed no solution or you have a big in your program. Debug to find it.

@ Cincinnatus I solved this task many times and the result is always the same - 210. You advised me to explore deeper, and now it gives the answer - 210 and allocation of transport flows is correct. But there is a problem (at least in my eyes): it takes about 3 minutes to find the solution.
P.s. Thanks for your help :-)

Ok, well it means that the solution is quite deep and the algorithm you developed takes a long time finding it.

One problem with this code only does num_demands iterations of improvement, each iteration taking from only one supply. However, in this case, to get a complete assignment some demands need to draw from multiple supplies, thus never hitting that all(d == 0 for d in node.demand_left) condition.

Another problem is that there is no good bound heuristic. The comparison if new_cost < best_cost is based on a partial solution, essentially assuming the rest will be fulfilled for free. At this point, it's not branch and bound, it's Dijkstra
